# Screen displayed as blank in RCP 4.8 in compatibility mode

Tags: eclipse, migration, rcp, eclipse-photon

While using the same code of RCP 3.6 in 4.8, in compatibility mode, application is started and home page is available. Some of the screens are displayed as blank in 4.8 .Some views are not being rendered. Could anyone please help.

Comment: This is far too vague to be able to help. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages. There are huge changes in Eclipse internals between 3.6 and 4.8 so all sorts of things might be causing the problems.

Comment: Log file is present,but there are no specific messages. other than An internal error occurred during: "Workbench Auto-Save Background Job".

Comment: Some screens are displayed but only few screens are not displayed. Is there any rendering issue in compatibility mode.